# How to do a majority voting on columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has 10 different columns, `A1`, `A2`, ...,`A10`. These columns contain `y` or `n`. I'd like to create another column whose value is `y` if the majority of columns (`A1`, `A2`, ...,`A10`) are `y` and `n` otherwise. How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html):

```
df['majority'] = df.mode(axis=1)[0]
```

#### Example

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['y', 'n'], size=(10, 10)))
print(df)

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  y  n  n  y  n  n  n  n  n  n
1  n  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  y  n
2  y  n  n  y  y  n  n  n  n  y
3  n  y  n  y  n  n  y  n  n  y
4  y  n  y  n  n  n  n  n  y  n
5  y  n  n  n  n  y  n  y  y  n
6  n  y  n  y  n  y  y  y  y  y
7  n  n  y  y  y  n  n  y  n  y
8  y  n  y  n  n  n  n  n  n  y
9  n  n  y  y  n  y  y  n  n  y

df['majority'] = df.mode(axis=1)[0]
print(df)

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 majority
0  y  n  n  y  n  n  n  n  n  n        n
1  n  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  y  n        y
2  y  n  n  y  y  n  n  n  n  y        n
3  n  y  n  y  n  n  y  n  n  y        n
4  y  n  y  n  n  n  n  n  y  n        n
5  y  n  n  n  n  y  n  y  y  n        n
6  n  y  n  y  n  y  y  y  y  y        y
7  n  n  y  y  y  n  n  y  n  y        n
8  y  n  y  n  n  n  n  n  n  y        n
9  n  n  y  y  n  y  y  n  n  y        n
```

---

If it is necessary to handle the distinction between true majority and split decisions, you could use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). eg:

```
mode = df.mode(axis=1)

df['majority'] = np.where(mode.isna().any(1), mode[0], 'split')
print(df)

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 majority
0  y  n  n  y  n  n  n  n  n  n        n
1  n  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  y  n        y
2  y  n  n  y  y  n  n  n  n  y        n
3  n  y  n  y  n  n  y  n  n  y        n
4  y  n  y  n  n  n  n  n  y  n        n
5  y  n  n  n  n  y  n  y  y  n        n
6  n  y  n  y  n  y  y  y  y  y        y
7  n  n  y  y  y  n  n  y  n  y    split
8  y  n  y  n  n  n  n  n  n  y        n
9  n  n  y  y  n  y  y  n  n  y    split
```