# What is the best PySpark practice to filter spark dataframe for voting system on certain columns?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm struggling to create an *efficient* voting system on spark dataframe to apply on certain columns for selecting desired records/rows . Let's say my data looks as below:

```
+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+----------+
|   Names  |     A     |      B      |     C    |    D     |
+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+----------+
|        X1|       true|         true|      true|      true|
|        X5|      false|         true|      true|     false|
|        X2|      false|        false|     false|     false|
|        X3|       true|         true|      true|     false|
|        X4|      false|        false|     false|      true|
|        X5|      false|         true|      true|     false|
|        X3|       true|         true|      true|     false|
+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+----------+
```

I want to create a new column name `majority`, which counts number of `true` for each rows and if it is:

- more than 50%, label it `abnormal`
- equal as `true`, label it `50-50`
- less than 50%, label it `normal`
  I try to inspire by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55749310/10452700) in absence of `DataFrame.mode` in spark dataframe and make `def df_mode(df)` function as below using window partition as they they offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36695251/10452700) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44807212/10452700):
  I tried to use regex to read `true`/`false` an count them but it is stupid:

```
def get_mode(df):
    counts = df.groupBy(['Names', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']).count().alias('count')
    #counts.show()
    win = Window().partitionBy('A', 'B', 'C', 'D').orderBy(F.col('count').desc())
    result = (counts
              .withColumn('majority', F.rank().over(win))
              #.where(F.col('majority) == 1)
              #.select('x', 'y')
             )
    #result.show()
        
    return result
df = get_mode(df)

def voting_sys(df):
    partition_columns = df.columns[1:]
    vote_results = (df  
    .withColumn('majority', F
        .over(Window.partitionBy(partition_columns))
        .when(F.isnull('majority'), '-')
        .when(F.regexp_extract('majority', '(?i)^true', 0) >  F.regexp_extract('majority', '(?i)^false', 0), 'abnormal')   
        .when(F.regexp_extract('majority', '(?i)^true', 0) == F.regexp_extract('majority', '(?i)^false', 0), '50-50')       
        .when(F.regexp_extract('majority', '(?i)^true', 0) <  F.regexp_extract('majority', '(?i)^false', 0), 'normal') 
        #.otherwise('normal') 
                                                                                  
    #.show()
)
        
    return vote_results
```

Note: I'm not interested to hack it using `df.toPandas()`.

Comment: You could try converting the `bools` to `int`, then taking an average of the four columns and storing it in a fourth column. This would give you a number between 0 and 1

Comment: @LiamFiddler You mean to encode the A, B, C, D columns? that might be expensive (encoding and scaling by vectorizing) but thanks for you input.

Comment: No, you can simply cast the dtype from Boolean to Integer. No encoding necessary.

Comment: I'm assuming the true / false are stored as Booleans rather than strings; are they stored as strings?

Comment: Short question: in general sorting with *priority* using `orderBy()` is expensive than using `filtering()` in spark frame if I want to sort the records/rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love the idea of @LiamFiddler casting Boolean to Integer. However, I'm not recommending using UDF here, it's unnecessary.

First, you **can** convert from string to Boolean, then from Boolean to Integer, like so `F.col(c).cast('boolean').cast('int')`, this transformation I believe is not as expensive as it might sound like.

Second, you don't have to hardcode the columns here (A, B, C, D), you can do the sum `sum(F.col(c) for c in cols]`

This is my working code

```py
cols = df.columns[1:]
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

(df
    .withColumn('sum', sum([F.col(c).cast('boolean').cast('int') for c in cols]))
    .withColumn('majority', F
        .when(F.col('sum')  > len(cols) / 2, 'abnormal')
        .when(F.col('sum') == len(cols) / 2, '50-50')
        .when(F.col('sum')  < len(cols) / 2, 'normal')
    )
    
    # order by abnormal, 50-50, normal
    .orderBy(F
        .when(F.col('majority') == 'abnormal', 1)
        .when(F.col('majority') == '50-50', 2)
        .when(F.col('majority') == 'normal', 3)
    )
    .show()
)

# Output
# +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+--------+
# |Names|    A|    B|    C|    D|sum|majority|
# +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+--------+
# |   X3| true| true| true|false|  3|abnormal|
# |   X3| true| true| true|false|  3|abnormal|
# |   X1| true| true| true| true|  4|abnormal|
# |   X5|false| true| true|false|  2|   50-50|
# |   X5|false| true| true|false|  2|   50-50|
# |   X4|false|false|false| true|  1|  normal|
# |   X2|false|false|false|false|  0|  normal|
# +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+--------+
```

Comment: Honestly, I was thinking of using using `XOR` or `XNOR` to resolve this issue but you nail it. So by this, I don't need to use to calculate dataframe **mode** using `groubBy()` to get  `count()` (in general no needs to the 1st function `def get_mode(df)`). Is it Ok if you form your answer `def voting_sys(df):`  to have a solid answer. maybe sort the rows by `abnormal`, then `50-50` & `normal`.

Comment: Well I'm not a big fan of wrapping transformations to functions like that. You can consider using [transform](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform) function instead of Python function.

Comment: and I updated my answer to sort the df as well

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be casting the Booleans as Integers, then taking an average of the four columns, which gives you a number between 0 and 1.

```
# if the values are stored as strings, you'll need a UDF to convert bool:
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

def true_false(s):
    return int(s.lower() == 'true')

tf_udf = udf(lambda x: true_false(x), IntegerType())

for c in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
    df.withColumn(c, tf_udf(col(c)))

df.withColumn('majority', (df.A + df.B + df.C + df.D) / 4)
```

Comment: I prefer to avoid using UDF if it's possible. UDF is like a black box to PySpark, and thus spark cannot efficiently apply optimizations on them. However, I just noticed that your idea about converting `boolean` values into `int` using *casting* (not encoding) is not expensive and make sense.

Comment: Cool, wasn't sure if the values were already stored as bools or not, but if so, then casting to ints is quite easy.